# Milliseconds timer matlab

Tags: matlab, timer, milliseconds

I am an amateur Matlab User who is attempting to write a code to run a specific function call every 10ms for a time span of 1 second.  I am having trouble trying to get something to run for the exact amount of time; I have tried to use Tic and Toc but that's in seconds (I need millisecond precision).  Here is some very basic code I have been playing with to try and get readings using a function called getvelocity.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
function [ velocity ] = Vel()
i=1;
timerID=tic;

while (toc(timerID) <=2);
    [v(i)]=vpx_GetTotalVelocity;
    disp (v(i));
    i=i+1;
end
velocity=mean(v);


end
```

The code above runs for two seconds; however, I want to run in ms precision.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the function you have is fast enough (not a trivial assumption) you can achieve it like so:

```
tic
for t = 0.01:0.01:1 %If you want the first function call to start right away you can change this to 0:0.01:0.99
    while toc < t
    end
    t %Put your function call here.
end
```

Note that 0.01 sec is 10 ms

Comment: If you just want to wait 10 ms between function calls, use `pause(0.01)` between them.

Comment: @Lama Accuracy was not really mentioned, but indeed Java's Thread.Sleep should prove to be more accurate: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/pause-for-the-better/